# How do I enable "Waiting <service>", "Preparing WIndows" login text?

Tags: windows, windows-10, services, login-screen

While I am searching google `How to enable preparing windows login test`/`How to enable informative text in my login screen` but no luck.
I searched in `Local Security Policies` but it isn't there.
In the youtube there's tutorial for *disabling it*.
Why I need "Waiting "/"Preparing Windows" you might ask?
I want to track down what service causing the windows to boot very slow.
Helps appreciated.

Comment: Seems like an X-Y question: I truly don't understand how text on the login screen can help with analysing a slow boot. I suggest to try disabling hibernation mode via an elevated CMD using the command `powercfg.exe -h off`.

Comment: Make a new, test, Windows User Profile (Account). Make it a member of Admin group. Restart and log into the new Account. Does this work? or do you have a bigger Operating System issue?

Comment: @harrymc so i can see the service that was slowest so i can disable/uninstall

Comment: @John i just want to see what service is slowest

Comment: That can be hard to root out. Try SysInternals Process Explorer and Process Monitor.  Could take more time than trying another user.

Comment: Could this event log help: `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance%4Operational.evtx`. Otherwise I would first try a boot PML, followed by a boot trace with Windows Performance Recorder. The SDK will get you wprui.exe when you install Windows Performance Toolkit - One of the scenarios to trace is boot.

Comment: @HelpingHand it only show the shutdown event not the start up event